# Not finding my bookdown bibliography file

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown, bibliography

My document is simply this

```
---
title: "The Visual Speech (VISP) Handbook"
author: "Fredrik Karlsson & Linda Sandström"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bibliography: references.bib
  #bookdown::pdf_book: default
  bookdown::gitbook: default
  biblio-style: "apalike"
  link-citations: true
---
# Preface {-}

[@R-base]
```

and I have a reference file:

```
> dir(pattern = "*.bib")
[1] "references.bib"
```

but I am unable to find this bib file when knitting the book:

> Error in eval(parse(text = name)) : object 'references.bib' not found
> Calls:  ... create_output_format ->
> create_output_format_function -> eval -> eval Please delete _main.Rmd
> after you finish debugging the error. Execution halted

Any ideas on how to set this up properly (in Rstudio)

Thanks!

Fredrik

Answer (score 2):

It's just a location problem in the code (see [more information here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html)).

You could try:

```
---
title: "The Visual Speech (VISP) Handbook"
author: "Fredrik Karlsson & Linda Sandström"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  #bookdown::pdf_book: default
  bookdown::gitbook: default
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: "apalike"
link-citations: true
---
# Preface {-}

[@R-base]
```